# Setting up zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans

I'm trying to set up Zend framework on my netbeans.When I run the application I get the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Documents and Settings\maryb\Desktop\ZEND\ZendFrameworkQuickstart-20100208\public\index.php
```

and the following error:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path='C:\Documents and Settings\maryb\Desktop\ZEND\ZendFrameworkQuickstart-20100208\library;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Documents and Settings\maryb\Desktop\ZEND\ZendFrameworkQuickstart-20100208\public\index.php on line 17
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add Zend Library in the required path. Have a look at following code in your `projectfolder/public/index.php` file:

```
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

Comment: Set the correct path to your library in `project-folder/public/index.php` or add your Zend library at correct location accordingly.

Comment: usually we add **Zend Library** in `projectd-folder/library/Zend`